# Shiny R using aggregate function

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using the ggplot2 and using the input from shiny as follows which works nicely:

```
geom_text(aes(label=n),data=cbind(aggregate(formula(paste0("n ~ " , 
input$yv)) , b,sum), gender = "total") )
```

But I can add a second Shiny input 'input$xv' instead of hard coding "gender" eg this does not work:

```
geom_text(aes(label=n),data=cbind(aggregate(formula(paste0("n ~ " , 
input$yv)) , b,sum), input$xv = "total") )
```

I have been trying for hours, anyone has any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be multiple ways to do what you want. One way would be as follows:

```
df = aggregate(formula(paste0("n ~ " ,input$yv)) , b,sum)
df[[input$xv]] = 'total'

geom_text(aes(label=n), data = df)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time. This works nicely,

Comment: Glad I could help! If you would consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your issue, that would be great.